# Is it possible to change and save I2C address programatically?

Tags: i2c

I want to drive 3 i2c devices on a single i2c line. Is it possible to achieve this without using A0,A1,A2 pins?
I thought the address of i2c devices should be programmatically changeable.
2 mcp23017 and si5351 chips I use.

Comment: *Some* I2C devices can have their addresses changed programatically, most can't. The datasheet will tell you. You could drive the Ax pins from the Arduino to change them at will, but to what end?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the address configuration pins? That's exactly what they are there for.

Comment: @Mat bc hw designer forget to connect these pins to mcu :(
  If it was OK to change programmatically, this would make my life easier.

Comment: If the pins are not connected in hardware (left open floating), the MCP23017 will show undefined behavior. It may randomly change addresses (even during operation), which is useless. These pins must be connected properly.

Comment: @projecti2c: you don't connect these pins to the MCU (in usual settings). You look at the datasheet and tie them e.g. to ground or VCC depeding on what address you want. The address selection pins don't change during normal operations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the datasheets of the 2 mentioned chips, they don't provide a way to change the address programmatically over the I2C bus. They only have address pins, which have to be tied to Vcc or ground for setting the address. Most ready to use boards with such chips already have pullup or pulldown resistors for this. If you use the blank chips, you absolutely need to tie the address pins to a fixed value. Normally this is done semi-permanently.

You can also connect the address pins to Arduino output pins to dynamically change the addresses.

There is no other way to change the addresses but to use the address pins.